# compare 2 dataframes and traverse 1st dataframe each n evry row so that validate corresponding column values in 2nd df

Tags: pandas, dataframe

compare 2 dataframes and traverse 1st dataframe each n every row so that validate corresponding column values in 2nd df.
In 2nd df column values are unique.but in 1st df rows may be 10000 rows.
sample code:
'''

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'unique_id': 
     ['Computer','iPhone','Printer','Desktop','Computer','iPhone','iphpne','Printer','Desktop','Computer','iPhone','Printer','Desktop'],
        'category': 
         ['movies','documentary','series','special','movies','documentary','series','special','series','special','movies','series','special'],
         'subcategory':
         ['drama','horror','comedy','reality','drama','documentary','comedy','reality','documentary','comedy','documentary','comedy','drama']
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns= ['unique_id', 'category','subcategory'])
print(df1)

data2 = {'unique_id': ['Computer','iPhone','Printer','Desktop'],
         'category': ['movies','documentary','series','special'],
         'subcategory':['drama','horror','comedy','reality']
        }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns= ['unique_id', 'category','subcategory'])
print(df2)
```

'''
#output:iterate each row in df1 and compare corresponding all values #are matching in df2 if not matching append index.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by specifying `how='outer'` in the [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer')
```

If you want to preserve the row order from df:

```py
# Append new values to df2 based on non-row-matches from df1
df2.append(df1.loc[(~df1.isin(df2)).all(axis=1)])

# Or the other way around
df1.append(df2.loc[(~df2.isin(df1)).all(axis=1)])
```

Comment: above one is not giving result.as in df1 10000 rows with duplicates and in df1 msy be 20 unique rows which are already there in df1.now i want to compare every row from df1 go and check in df2 is it available if it is not in df2  then pickup that row index and again 2nd row from df1 going to check all the rows in df2 if there ok else append index.can anyone help me out please.